# Get the count in a separate column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I currently have the following table:

```
REF| STATUS
OP1|0
OP2|2
OP2|4
OP2|5
OP3|7
OP3|6
```

As you can see, there are 3 statueses for OP2 and 2 statuses for OP3.
I am trying to archive the following:

```
REF| STATUS | COUNT
OP1|0       |1
OP2|2       |3
OP2|4       |3
OP2|5       |3
OP3|7       |2
OP3|6       |2
```

Count being the number of status for each ref.

I have provided a SQL however not sure what  I am going wrong?

```
SELECT ref,STATUS, (SELECT COUNT(STATUS) FROM orders WHERE STATUS > 0 GROUP BY ref)
FROM orders
```

I am using SQL server 2008.

Answer (score 6):

Use `COUNT() OVER()`

```
SELECT ref,STATUS, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY REF1)
FROM orders
```

To get the count where status > 0, the above query can be changed to

```
SELECT ref,STATUS, COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS>0 THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY REF1)
FROM orders
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a correlated subquery:

```
select ref
 , status
 , (
  select count(i.status)
  from orders i
  where i.status > 0
    and i.ref = o.ref
  ) as OrderCount  
from orders o
```

an `inner join` will probably be more efficient though:

```
select 
   o.ref
 , o.status
 , i.OrderCount 
from orders o
  left join (
    select 
        ref
      , count(i.status) as OrderCount 
    from orders i
    where i.status > 0
    group by ref
  ) i
    on i.ref = o.ref
```

Comment: this worked - only change needed was  OrderCount = count(i.status) to count(i.status) as OrderCount.